# PHP inline sql much faster than stored procedure

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, oci8

I am in the process of working with our DBA to convert all of our php inline sql to stored procedures.  I'm finding that the stored procedures which execute the same sql as the original inline sql run much much slower.  For instance I have 1 query that will run in 1 second inline versus 10 seconds via stored procedure.  Another that runs in 8 seconds inline and 15 minutes via stored procedure.  Does anyone have any idea why there is such a performance difference between the two?

I am running php 5.6.33-1

```
OCI8 Support    enabled  
OCI8 DTrace Support disabled  
OCI8 Version    2.0.9  
Revision    $Id: 74e302c766329dcc183df9ea0359f733df8d192c $  
Oracle Run-time Client Library Version  11.2.0.4.0  
Oracle Compile-time Instant Client Version  11.2  
Directive   Local Value Master Value  
oci8.connection_class   no value    no value  
oci8.default_prefetch   100 100  
oci8.events Off Off  
oci8.max_persistent -1  -1  
oci8.old_oci_close_semantics    Off Off  
oci8.persistent_timeout -1  -1  
oci8.ping_interval  60  60  
oci8.privileged_connect Off Off  
oci8.statement_cache_size   20  20  

Statistics  
Active Persistent Connections   1  
Active Connections  1
```

Here is the code

```
function runSP($cid) {
        $conn = oci_connect('XXX', 'XXX', 'XXX');
        $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'begin WEB.XXSD_WEB_OVERVIEW.CUSTOMER_INVOICES (:cid,:rc,:err); end;');
        $refcur = oci_new_cursor($conn);
        oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':cid',$cid);
        oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':rc', $refcur, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR);
        oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':err',$err, 100);
        oci_execute($stid);

        oci_set_prefetch($refcur, 200);
        oci_execute($refcur);
        $rows = [];
        while ($row = oci_fetch_array($refcur, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }

        oci_free_statement($refcur);
        oci_free_statement($stid);
        oci_close($conn);
        return $rows;
    }

    function inlineSql($cid) {
        $sql = 'select  th.customer_trx_id customer_id, th.trx_number, aps.status, th.trx_date, th.purchase_order,
                  th.interface_header_attribute1 order_id, upper(cav.city) city, upper(cav.state) state,
                  aps.status, round(sysdate-aps.due_date) past_due, th.invoice_currency_code,
                  nvl(aps.amount_due_original,0) original,
                  -(nvl(aps.amount_applied,0)) receipts,
                  nvl(aps.amount_credited,0) credits,
                  nvl(aps.amount_adjusted,0) adjustments,
                  -(nvl(aps.discount_taken_earned,0) + nvl(aps.discount_taken_unearned,0)) discount,
                  nvl(aps.amount_due_remaining,0) balance
                from ar.ar_payment_schedules_all aps, ar.ra_customer_trx_all th, xxsd_cust_addr_v cav
                where
                th.customer_trx_id = aps.customer_trx_id
                and th.bill_to_customer_id = :cid
                and th.batch_source_id <> 1023
                and th.ship_to_site_use_id = cav.site_use_id(+)
                order by  trx_date desc';
        $conn = oci_connect('XXX', 'XXX', 'XXX');
        $stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
        oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':cid',$cid);
        oci_execute($stid);

        $rows = [];
        while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }

        oci_free_statement($stid);
        oci_close($conn);
        return $rows;
    }
runSP(182574); //super slow, 10+ seconds
inlineSql(182574); //1 second
```

Here is the stored procedure I am calling:

```
PROCEDURE CUSTOMER_INVOICES (
      P_CUSTOMER_ID   IN     APPS.RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_ALL.BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ID%TYPE DEFAULT NULL,
      P_REF_CURSOR       OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
      X_ERR_MSG          OUT VARCHAR2)
   IS
   BEGIN
      OPEN P_REF_CURSOR FOR
           ---Params:    customer_id

           SELECT TH.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID CUSTOMER_ID,
                  TH.TRX_NUMBER,
                  APS.STATUS,
                  TH.TRX_DATE,
                  TH.PURCHASE_ORDER,
                  TH.INTERFACE_HEADER_ATTRIBUTE1 ORDER_ID,
                  UPPER (CAV.CITY) CITY,
                  UPPER (CAV.STATE) STATE,
                  APS.STATUS,
                  ROUND (SYSDATE - APS.DUE_DATE) PAST_DUE,
                  TH.INVOICE_CURRENCY_CODE,
                  NVL (APS.AMOUNT_DUE_ORIGINAL, 0) ORIGINAL,
                  - (NVL (APS.AMOUNT_APPLIED, 0)) RECEIPTS,
                  NVL (APS.AMOUNT_CREDITED, 0) CREDITS,
                  NVL (APS.AMOUNT_ADJUSTED, 0) ADJUSTMENTS,
                  - (  NVL (APS.DISCOUNT_TAKEN_EARNED, 0)
                     + NVL (APS.DISCOUNT_TAKEN_UNEARNED, 0))
                     DISCOUNT,
                  NVL (APS.AMOUNT_DUE_REMAINING, 0) BALANCE
             FROM AR.AR_PAYMENT_SCHEDULES_ALL APS,
                  AR.RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_ALL TH,
                  WEB.XXSD_CUST_ADDR_V CAV
            WHERE     TH.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID = APS.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID
                  AND TH.BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ID = P_CUSTOMER_ID
                  AND TH.BATCH_SOURCE_ID <> 1023
                  AND TH.SHIP_TO_SITE_USE_ID = CAV.SITE_USE_ID(+)
         ORDER BY TRX_DATE DESC;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN INVALID_CURSOR
      THEN
         X_ERR_MSG := 'INVALID_CURSOR';
      WHEN INVALID_NUMBER
      THEN
         X_ERR_MSG := 'INVALID_NUMBER';
      WHEN PROGRAM_ERROR
      THEN
         X_ERR_MSG := 'PROGRAM_ERROR';
      WHEN VALUE_ERROR
      THEN
         X_ERR_MSG := 'VALUE_ERROR';
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         X_ERR_MSG := 'ERROR IN SQL';
   END;
```

Comment: Couple of things to look at:  (1) run them several times and in different order.  The SP might have done all the physical I/O and heavy lifting, and the INLINE got all the benefit.  (2)  Run a database trace on both to make sure the time is not being lost elsewhere

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: You are calling oci_set_prefetch() in one case but not the other.  Set it in both cases - and tune the value.  (If I had to guess, I'd say you chose 200 from the example given in places like p201 of the Underground PHP & Oracle Manual!)

Comment: @Connor - Good suggestions.  However the inline sql ran for years without issue.  It's only until migrating these queries to SPs that they have become unbearably slow.   I'll have the dba run a trace.

Comment: @ChristopherJones -  I have actually tried various values of prefetch on both functions as well as the default on both.  I just forgot to remove the prefetch statement from the SP code after my last batch of tests.  I have found that if I run the SPs versus the plain sql in sqldeveloper the SPs run much slower there as well.  Maybe it has something to do with an oracle configuration?

Comment: You are using 11.2 client so you should have prefetching support for REF CURSORS (https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/oracle-database-11gr2-enhancements-for-php) but I wonder what you would see if you tried a PIPE (https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/converting-ref-cursor-to-pipe-for-performance-in-php-oci8-and-pdooci)?

Comment: In a prior comment I noted that stored procedures were running slower than the equivalent  inline sql from SqlDeveloper.  I was wrong on that.  SqlDeveloper defaults to returning a max of 5000 records for stored procedures and 50 records for a plain query.  Thats where the time differences were coming in.

Comment: Ultimately I never found a solution to this problem.  We recently upgraded oracle to 12g and now stored procedures run at the same speed as inline sql on average.